# How to handle multiple instances of class running concurrently and independently in an "OOP" fashion?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, concurrency

Is it possible, from OOP standpoint, to create the following program:

1. If I have a Tracker class that is supposed to track several web-queried data, can I have multiple Tracker instances (~50) running concurrently and querying different data? **
2. Can I have each Tracker object pass its data (when necessary) to an array inside a Processor class that I have also created?
3. Can the Processor class run simultaneously in the background processing the data the Tracker objects deliver, continuously?

To clarify, is it possible to create multiple class instantiations that run concurrently with the main program and pass data to a common variable? How could this be implemented while avoiding prob;ems where the main program is accessing the common variable while the Tracker instances are passing data to it? The program is meant to run indefinitely.

Is the scenario I am thinking of related to Threading in Java, or is it more advanced, or something else entirely?

I understand this is an involved question and I appreciate any and all answers. Please note that while I have pseudo-code, I have not written any of the actual code yet. I want to get some nudges in the right direction before I start.

I am looking into @Soana's answr, but more answers would also be great!

Comment: Classical producer-consumer-example with Threads, I suppose :-)

Comment: Each Tracker object has a method that retrieves the data and sends it along to the Processor class's array if necessary. So, I need 50 Tracker objects running their retrieval methods simultaneously.

Comment: Have you heard of Executors, Callable, Future? They might be worth investigating.

Comment: There is only one instance of the `Processor`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do exactly what you stated?

- Give your `Processor` a queue (e.g. a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), which is designed for exactly these purposes)
- start 50 Threads, which execute the `Tracker`'s method. Give them a reference to the queue of the `Processor`
- Run the `Processor` somewhere (the main thread, where the main-method executes, or in an additional thread)
- When you determined that enough data was tracked/processed, shutdown all the `Tracker`-threads and the `Processor`-thread
- join all the threads in you main thread